# как при клике остановить воспроизведение аудио!

Tags: javascript, android, html5, аудио

есть Код JS и только так он работает на телефоне, по другому никак!!!

На странице 20 блоков со своим аудио файлом внутри этого блока.
выглядит так!

И клик по каждому элементу играет своя мелодия!! тоесть кликаем на любой элемент играет звук, если кликать на второй то у предыдущего остановился звук, а у текущего на котор кликнули начал играть мелодия!!

```
<div class="test">
    <p>БЛОК-1!</p>
    <audio src="1.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"></audio>
</div>
```

Таких блоков может быть 1000!!!

Вот JS код который обрабатывает код!

```
var blocks = document.querySelectorAll('.test');
                for(var i = 0; i < blocks.length; i++) {
                     var block = blocks[i];

                     block.onclick = function() {
                         //действие при клике
                                var path = '/android_asset/www/audio/';
                                var audioName = this.querySelector('audio').getAttribute('src');
                                var fullPath = path+audioName;
                                var local1 = new Media(fullPath);
                                local1.play();
                     }//конец функции
           }//конец цикла
     }
```

вопрос как при клике на другой элемент остановить воспроизведение аудио файла?
И да если перевести переменную в глобальный то не работает!!(вынести из функции).

есть методы клика. `play(); stop(); pause();`

мучаюсь уже который день.
предложили в одном форуме этот код, на браузере он работает идеально, но не работает на андроид приложение ниже 5.0, а 5.0 и выше без нареканий!!
[ССЫЛКА НА КОД JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Rashit1122233/zbsbrwk0/2/)

Answer (score 1):

Вот так

```js
document.addEventListener('play', function(e) {
  var audios = document.getElementsByTagName('audio');
  for(var i = 0; i < audios.length; i++) {
    if(audios[i] != e.target) {
      audios[i].pause();
    }
  }
}, true);
```

```html
Аллесандро Марчелло - 1. Andante (oboe concert)
            <br><audio id="audio1" preload="metadata" controls>
    <source src="http://xn----7sbab5aqcbiddtdj1e1g.xn--p1ai/mp3/music/a.marcello/Аллесандро Марчелло - 1. Andante (oboe concert).mp3">
    <track label="Аллесандро Марчелло - 1. Andante (oboe concert)">
   </audio><br><br>
   Аллесандро Марчелло - 2. Adagio (oboe concert)
   <br><audio id="audio2" preload="metadata" controls>
    <source src="http://xn----7sbab5aqcbiddtdj1e1g.xn--p1ai/mp3/music/a.marcello/Аллесандро Марчелло - 2. Adagio (oboe concert).mp3">
    <track label="Аллесандро Марчелло - 2. Adagio (oboe concert)">
   </audio><br><br>
   Аллесандро Марчелло - 3. Presto (oboe concert)
      <br><audio id="audio3" preload="metadata" controls>
    <source src="http://xn----7sbab5aqcbiddtdj1e1g.xn--p1ai/mp3/music/a.marcello/Аллесандро Марчелло - 3. Presto (oboe concert).mp3">
    <track label="Аллесандро Марчелло - 3. Presto (oboe concert)">
   </audio><br><br>
```

Comment: ID у элементов не обязательны

Comment: 1  у тебя он проходит по всем тегам аудио найденных элементов.

2 в твоих аудио файлах установлен controls. который на экране видны, а у меня он не приемлен!!

3. посмотри как образуется у меня путь к файлу.

Comment: Я подкинул идею о том, как я это реализовал. Ты можешь подчерпнуть из моего кода только то, что тебе нужно. Мы же здесь не пишем программы на заказ, а подсказываем.

Comment: Спасибо на этом, просто есть конитель в этих мобильных приложениях, а так если в браузере то на JQ это легко организовать.
вопрос такой, как грамотно вывести из функции переменную, и сделать ее глобальной, только чтоб он сохранил тот же путь при клике?